# Loading data to Bigquery from Google Cloud Storage using web-ui

Tags: google-bigquery

I followed the guideline,["Loading Data From Cloud Datastore"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery), but failed to load my data from Google Cloud Storage.

Here is the summary of load job:

```
Error Reason:notFound.
Errors: Not found: URI gs://tt-history.appspot.com/backups/backups-agxzfnR0LWhpc3RvcnlyQQsSHF9BRV9EYXRhc3RvcmVBZG1pbl9PcGVyYXRpb24YiZ76AgwLEhZfQUVfQmFja3VwX0luZm9ybWF0aW9uGAEM.Trend.backup_info
```

I checked the path of object. Any idea?

Comment: The GCS link must be under the same project that your BQ is.

Comment: Yes both of them are in the same project. (I checked them by BQ's url which contains my project id, and also for GCS it is enabled for same project.)

Comment: Can you provide the BigQuery project id and job id of a failed load job? We can investigate to see what the problem might be.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. App ID: tt-history Job ID: tt-history:job_HwA1xkEpzI-9mJNEqorSw4Sm96Q

Comment: Thank you for the job id. I've found the failure and am currently investigating the root cause. Progress may be delayed due to the upcoming US July 4th holiday. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thanks. By the way I downloaded my backup from GCS and converted to csv. It is not urgent anymore.